# Select statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing or punctuation is incorrect

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I cannot for the life of me figure out why I am getting this error. I am pretty familiar with VB and SQL but am not used to using Access. I have ran my query separately just in access and it works just fine... Below is my code. Any suggestions!?!? Thanks so much!!!

```
Private Sub Command18_Click()
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim sSQL As String

sSQL = "SELECT Count(*) AS Duration" _
         & "FROM [Project_Duration_Info] " _
         & "WHERE [Project - Consulting Partner] In (Select [CP_Name] from [CP's] " _
                                               & "Where [CP_DDL] = [Forms]![Consulting Partners]![CPs]) " _
        & "AND [Project - Actual Complete Date] >= [Forms]![Consulting Partners]![FromDate] " _
        & "AND  [Project - Actual Complete Date] < [Forms]![Consulting Partners]![ToDate]"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
Me.Duration = rs!Durations
Else
Me.Duration = ""
End If
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: "Project - Consulting Partner" is that a legal field name? What about from [CP's] where you also reference [CPs]? Are those separate tables?

Comment: Anything is a legal field name if you surround it with [] (No matter how hideous it makes query writing).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are combining VBA and SQL into one statement: `[Forms]![Consulting Partners]![CPs]` appears to be a variable pulled from the form but embedded within the SQL try

```
WHERE [CP_DDL] = '" & [Forms]![Consulting Partners]![CPs] & "'
```

The same logic will need to be applied to the `[Forms]![Consulting Partners]![ToDate]` and `[Forms]![Consulting Partners]![FromDate]` and if these are dates you'll probably need to surround them with # (so end result would be *#01/01/2012#*)